# Trying to convert a received outlook e-mail to rich text, and set font

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a user who receives a system generated e-mail that is formatted with a font such that when it is rendered in outlook the columns of text do not line up. I know what font it needs, and it's installed on the user's PC. In groupwise, he was able to simply change the font on the message after he received it and all was well. However, it seems that there is no functionality for that in Outlook (which we recently moved to).

The fix that was suggested on the Microsoft forum was to use a rule when the message is received to run a VBA script, and convert the message to RTF, then set the font.

This is my first foray into VBA, though I've done a couple small vb scripts in the past, so I'm probably way off base with the start, but here's what I tried.

```
Sub TestMessageRule(Message As Outlook.MailItem)
    Set Message.BodyFormat = 3
End Sub
```

I got an error with this, "Invalid use of a property", so I'm guessing you can't change it that way. I got 1=Plain text, 2=HTML, and 3=Rich Text by sending myself test e-mails with this code:

```
Sub TestMessageRule(Message As Outlook.MailItem)
    MsgBox Message.BodyFormat
End Sub
```

So, the question is, how can I change the BodyFormat property properly, or is there some better way I should be going about this?

Then if you're feeling particularly nice, maybe you could point me towards how to change the font of the body text.

Thanks,
Bryan

Here's what finally worked for me:

```
Sub TestMessageRule(Message As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim BodyString As String
    Message.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    BodyString = Replace(Message.HTMLBody, "<FONT SIZE=2>", "<FONT SIZE=3 FACE=""COMIC SANS MS"">")
    Message.HTMLBody = BodyString
    Message.Save
End Sub
```

Obviously Comic Sans MS is not my desired end font, but it stands out great for testing. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use "set" when setting a scalar property:

Message.BodyFormat = 3

That being said, simply read the plain text Body property and use it to construct the suitably formated HTML with the font specified, then set the HTMLBody property.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I haven't done anything with html in about 15 years, so I was a little concerned about how to properly format it, but it looks like when I set the bodyformat Outlook automatically creates the HTML, so now I've just got to figure out how to edit it.

Comment: Thanks again! Just realized there is a replace... everything's working great now!